# Decrypt Blockchain.info wallet export

Tags: blockchain.info

Blockchain.info's encrypted wallet format is [described](https://blockchain.info/wallet/wallet-format) as:

> AES encrypting the entire JSON payload with the users password which
>   is then encoded as base64. No salt is used for single pass encryption.
>   The exact AES specifications are 10 rounds of PBKDF2, Block Mode CBC
>   ISO10126 padding.

However, in trying to verify my own encrypted exports, it seems thats not all the information (or correct). I think part of the issue is in how the user's password is expanded to an input key for the AES/Rijndael cipher.

- The input key for AES can be 128, 192, or 256 bits; which is being used?
- AES has its own [key schedule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_key_schedule), but it seems Blockchain is using something separate, as "PBKDF2" is another key expansion function.
- PBKDF2 is a methodology that can be used with many types of hashes; which hash is being used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so after investigating the provided [restore tool](https://blockchain.info/DecryptWallet.html) (thanks Lohoris for pointing it out!), I arrived at the following answers to my questions:

- The input key for the AES decryption is 32 bytes (256 bits)
- The block size used is 16 bytes (`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` for [PHP mcrypt](http://php.net/mcrypt) functions)
- The initialization vector (IV) for the AES decryption is the first 16 bytes (one block size) of the encrypted string. The remaining encrypted string is the encrypted message.
- The user's password is expanded by using 10 rounds of PBKDF2 hashing, using SHA1 hashing, **and the IV as salt** (the "No salt is used for single pass encryption" note seems to just mean no salt for the AES encryption. For the PBKDF2 hashing, there is a salt).

Note, if using PHP `mcrypt` extension functions (like I was trying to), you need to use the `mdecrypt_generic()` method rather than `mcrypt_decrypt()`, since Blockchain using ISO10126 padding, and the `mcrypt` extension will only use "zero padding". You then have to un-pad the result separately.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't have a *direct* answer to your questions, I guess you can find those looking at the source of [the restore script](https://bitbucket.org/lohoris/mywallet-restore).

Comment: Thanks Lohoris; that got me on the right track! I did find that that particular restore script is outdated (the encryption method changed in March of 2012). Though it pointed me to [this working script](https://gist.github.com/anfedorov/2757171) and the [restore tool](https://blockchain.info/DecryptWallet.html) that helped me figure it out.